# How to change icon image of button on mouse entered/mouse exit in java

Tags: java, netbeans

here's my code.

```
    private void caddMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
setRolloverIcon(Icon) (no need for the MouseListener)
        cadd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cadd.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/rent/PNG/Add-Male.png")));
        cadd.setBackground(Color.black);
        cadd.setForeground(Color.white);
        //v.setBackground(Color.black);
    }
```

Comment: "*here's my code*" doesn't explain your problem. Do you have problem with compilation or maybe it runtime problem like thrown exception or incorrect result? Or maybe it works and you are just sharing solution?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - not a statement

Comment: this is my runtime error

Comment: i need to change my icon when i entered to the jbutton ...

Comment: What do you think is the purpose of this line `setRolloverIcon(Icon) (no need for the MouseListener)`? What is `Icon` and `(no need for the MouseListener)`?